# Convert hashmap to simple object in Groovy

Tags: json, dictionary, object, groovy, hashmap

I have a hashmap

```
[enable_api_security:[BOOL:false], owner:[S:abcd], approvers:[L:[[S:abcd]]]}
```

I want it to be simple object like this

```
{enable_api_security: false, owner: abcd, approvers: abcd}
```

How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by simple object? Plain hash map? Json?

Comment: Isn't `approvers` a list in that notation? Your "object" looks alot like some broken JSON or JS code. Also from your "toString" it's not clear whether `false` is already a boolean or it's a string and part of this transformation must take care of the type coercion.  And finally please add the code you have tried and what problems you faced.

Comment: All objects in Groovy have a type, there's no such thing as a "simple object"

Answer (score 0):

In groovy you can programmatically add new properties to any object through the object's [`metaClass`](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_metaclasses):

```
Object mapped = new Object()
mapped.metaClass."myNewProperty" = valueObj
```

Then you can access this new property as any other property in your custom object:

```
assert mapped.myNewProperty.equals(valueObj)
```

Then, using these features, you can create a new property in your custom object for every entry in a given `Map` (initialized with their corresponding value), like in following working demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

Map properties = [enable_api_security: false, owner: 'Hello', time: LocalDateTime.now()]

Object enhanced = new Object()
properties.each { key, value -> 
    enhanced.metaClass."$key" = value
}

println enhanced.enable_api_security
println enhanced.owner
println enhanced.time
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/groovy/so/a56204337)

Hope this helps.